# How many quests can you find on other quests?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Very occasionally on daily/weekly quests you can find a new quest in a container.

So far I have found two: "Vault 789" and "With Friends Like These".

Both gave multiple legendary rewards. Are there any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Fallout wiki](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Quest_clue) lists **five**.

- Welcome to Paradise
- With Friends Like These
- Factory Floor of Fear
- Vault 789
- The Mystery of Vault 666

So looks like I've got a few more years of daily quests to unlock them all.

Answer (score -1):

"Vault 789" and "With Friends Like These" are single-stage quests. These quests typically reward better items than daily or weekly quests.

Here's a link for all of the quest types.

[**SPOILERS** -- Fallout Shelter Quests Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_quests)

Comment: Why did I get a minus here? This is on-topic.

Comment: Probably because you did not answer the question.